# How to use PS4 controller with CLearpath Jackal?

Tags: ros, bluetooth, ros-melodic, clearpath, jackal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am struggling to use the PS4 controller supplied with the Clearpath Jackal for manual control. I can connect to it by running `sudo bluetoothctl` then `agent on` and `scan on` to get the Mac address and then running:

```
scan off
pair <MAC_ADDRESS>
trust <MAC_ADDRESS>
connect <MAC_ADDRESS>
```

This successfully connects to the controller but I get no response when I try to use it, i.e. the robot doesn't move. I've tried to run `hcitool dev` and `rfkill list all` to get more info. Here's the output I get:

```
administrator@user:~$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    D8:61:62:B3:2F:DE
administrator@user:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375106/how-to-use-ps4-controller-with-clearpath-jackal?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2021-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pedro1713](https://answers.ros.org/users/32895/pedro1713/) on 2021-03-31**:
The first time using a PS4 controller with a Husky, I wasn't aware that I needed to press one of the shoulder buttons to actually send commands.

**Comment by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) on 2021-03-31**:
Few follow ups that I am not sure I understand as part of you orginal question:
Is the device showing up in `/dev/` ? Are you able to use something like jstest to visualize joystick outputs?

Just trying to see if the issue is at the OS level or the ROS level

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2021-04-01**:
I've tried holding the `L1` button as well as moving the left joystick but there has been no response. The device `hci0` is not showing up in the `/dev` directory. I've just had a quick play with the command `jstest --event` and I get the message `jstest: No such file or directory`. Not sure if this is expected given that `hci0` is not in `/dev` or whether I've done something else wrong. `jstest` seemed to be preinstalled on the `Jackal` as the usage text displayed in the terminal after running the command `jstest` with no flags.

**Comment by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) on 2021-04-01**:
Can you check `/dev/input/` for a `js*` device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this issue by running `sudo apt-get install python-ds4drv`, `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` and then `sudo udevadm trigger` which then showed `/dev/input/js0` and `/dev/input/ps4` after running `ls -l /dev/input`.

---

Originally posted by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) with karma: 501 on 2021-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1